# agreed to/on/with

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know which preposition to go with "agree" in the following:

> Mrs. Murray wouldn’t take Pete’s excuse for being out late the other night, so she told Pete that he was grounded this weekend. Pete was really sorry for not being able to follow what he and his mother **agreed to/on/with**.

Comment: One person agrees **with** another; two people agree **to** or **on** a plan.

Comment: Or "he and his mother agreed upon"

Comment: Also, better with past perfect, "*Pete was really sorry for not being able to follow what he and his mother **had** agreed on*."